Let $f$, $g$ be two complex polynomials satisfying $f(x-1,y)g(x,y)=f(x,y)g(x-1,y-1)$, what we can say about $f$ and $g$?
Let $f$, $g$ be two non-zero polynomials in $\Bbb C[x,y]$ satisfying the identity
$$
f(x-1,y)g(x,y)=f(x,y)g(x-1,y-1).
$$
What we can say about $f$ and $g$?
In particular, if $f$, $g$ are two non-zero polynomials in $\Bbb C[x]$ satisfying
$$
f(x-1)g(x)=f(x)g(x-1),
$$
then we have $f(x)=cg(x)$, for some non-zero constant $c$.

One family of solutions is that $f(x,y)$ is a function only of $y$, and $g(x,y)$ is a function only of $x-y$.  Another is that $f(x,y) = g(x,y) = h(x)$ for some $h$.  Also, if $(f_1, g_1)$ is a solution, and $(f_2, g_2)$ is a solution, so is $(f_1 f_2, g_1 g_2)$.

Why are there votes to close this question?

Every irreducible factor of $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ is of the form $ax+by+\zeta$ for some integers $a$ and $b$, and some complex number $\zeta$.  We first need a lemma:
Lemma Let $h(x,y)$ be a polynomial and let $(a,b)$ be a nonzero vector. Suppose that $h(x,y)$ is a scalar multiple of $h(x+a, y+b)$. Then $h(x,y) = h(x+a, y+b)$, and $h$ is of the form $\prod_i (bx-ay+\zeta_i)$ for various scalars $\zeta_i$.
Proof Let $h(x,y) = u h(x+a,y+b)$. Comparing the highest degree terms on each side, we see that $u=1$. Then $h(x,y) = h(x+na, y+nb)$ for all integers $n$. Expanding this as a polynomial in $n$, all the coefficients of $n^j$ on each side must be equal, so we see that $h(x,y) = h(x+ta, y+tb)$ for all complex numbers $t$, and thus $h(x,y)$ is a function of $ay-bx$. By the fundamental theorem of algebra, any polynomial in $ay-bx$ factors as a product of linear terms. $\square$.
Let the irreducible factorization of $f(x,y)$ be $\prod_{i=1}^m \phi_i(x,y)$ and let the irreducible factorization of $g(x,y)$ be $\prod_{j=1}^n \gamma_j(x,y)$. We have
$$\prod_{i=1}^m \phi_i(x-1,y) \prod_{j=1}^n \gamma_j(x,y) = \prod_{i=1}^m \phi_i(x,y) \prod_{j=1}^n \gamma_j(x-1, y-1). \qquad \label{1}\tag{$\ast$}$$
So, the factors on the left hand side of \eqref{1} are the same as the factors on the right hand side, up to scalars. Choose a particular bijection from the LHS factor to the RHS factors, sending each factor to a scalar multiple of itself.
Make a directed graph with $m+n$ vertices corresponding to the $\phi_i$ and $\gamma_j$, and an edge from a vertex $u$ to a vertex $v$ if the factor corresponding to $u$ on the left becomes the factor corresponding to $v$ on the right. Every vertex has in-degree $1$ and out-degree $1$, so the graph is a disjoint union of directed cycles. Look at one particular cycle $C$. I'll show that all the factors in $C$ are products of linear forms as described above.
Suppose that $C$ has $p$ edges of type $\phi \to \phi$ , $q$ edges of type $\gamma$ to $\gamma$ and $r$ edges of types $\phi \to \gamma$ and $\gamma \to \phi$. (Note that there must be the same number of these two types.) Then, if $h(x,y)$ is a vertex of $C$, we have
$$h(x,y) = h(x+p-q, y-q-r). \label{2}\tag{$\dagger$}$$
Note that we cannot have $(p-q, -q-r) = (0,0)$, as the second coordinate would force $q=r=0$ and then the first would force $p=0$.
So the lemma applies to $h$, with $(a,b) = (p-q,-q-r)$, and $h$ is a product of linear factors as desired.
There are many such examples; I'll write out how to construct them when I have more time.

Okay, let's do an example. For any circular ordering of the symbols $\phi$ and $\gamma$, we get a family of solutions. As a running example, let's take the sequence $(\phi, \phi, \gamma, \phi, \gamma, \gamma, \phi)$. So $m=4$, $n=3$, $p=2$, $q = 1$ and $r = 2$. We want to find functions $\{ \phi_i : 1 \leq i \leq m \}$ and $\{ \gamma_j : 1 \leq j \leq n \}$ such that
$$\begin{array}{lcl}
\phi_1(x-1, y) &=& \phi_2(x,y) \\
\phi_2(x-1, y) &=& \gamma_1(x-1,y-1) \\
\gamma_1(x,y) &=& \phi_3(x,y) \\
\phi_3(x-1,y) &=& \gamma_2(x-1, y-1) \\
\gamma_2(x,y) &=& \gamma_3(x-1,y-1) \\
\gamma_3(x,y) &=& \phi_4(x,y) \\
\phi_4(x-1,y) &=& \phi_1(x,y)
\end{array}.$$
Concatenating them all, we want $\phi_1(x,y) = \phi_1(x+1, y-3)$, so we can take $\phi_1(x,y) = h(3x+y)$ for any polynomial $h$. Then
$$\begin{array}{lcl}
\phi_1(x,y) &=& h(3x+y) \\
\phi_2(x,y) &=& h(3x+y-3) \\
\gamma_1(x,y) &=& h(3x+y-2) \\
\phi_3(x,y) &=& h(3x+y-2) \\
\gamma_2(x,y) &=& h(3x+y-1) \\
\gamma_3(x,y) &=& h(3x+y+3) \\
\phi_4(x,y) &=& h(3x+y+3). \\
\end{array}$$
So
$$f(x,y) = h(3x+y) h(3x+y-3) h(3x+y-2) h(3x+y+3) \quad
g(x,y) = h(3x+y-2) h(3x+y-1) h(3x+y+3)$$
is a solution for any $h$.
